# How can I interpolate a missed value depending on the previous and next value?

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, awk

I have a large file with two columns, I would like to interpret the value at  0.00, 0.50, 1.00, 1.50 ...etc  **(if it is not already exist)** by calculating the mean from the previous value and the next value. For instance the corresponding value of **3.00** is missed so I want to add a line with 3.00 in the first column and a corresponding value in the second column =**(2.99 + 3.56)/2=3.14** and do the same for **3.50, 4.00 , 4.50 ...etc**
this is my input

```
0.00  0.29
0.50  0.79
1.00  1.31
1.50  1.86
2.00  2.42
2.50  2.99
3.25  3.56
3.75  4.15
4.25  4.73
4.75  5.32
5.00  5.92
5.50  6.53
6.00  7.15
```

and this my desired output

```
0.00    0.29
0.50    0.79
1.00    1.31
1.50    1.86
2.00    2.42
2.50    2.99
3.00    3.28
3.50    3.86
4.00    4.44
4.50    5.03
5.00    5.92
5.50    6.53
6.00    7.15
```

Comment: If the value for `x.00` is missing, is it guaranteed that the values for `(x-1).75` and `x.25` are present? Likewise for `x.25` and `x.75` if `x.50` is missing?

Comment: yes the file always like this, the maximum interval for the first column is 0.5 and the minimum interval is 0.25

Comment: This can be done with any language. Do you have a language of choice? What have you tried so far with it?

Comment: I have tried with awk but I cannot find reliable solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it in two steps.

First, interpolate the missing data. Here is an example with `awk`:

```
awk '
    ($1 - prev1) > 0.25 { printf "%.2f  %.2f\n", prev1 + 0.25, (prev2 + $2)/2 }
    { print; prev1 = $1; prev2 = $2 }
' data_file
```

It works like this:

- First, if we notice that a value in column 1 is missing (gap with previous value is > 0.25) we print the missing line by calculating an average for the column 2.
- Next, we print the current line and set the previous values for the next cycle

Finally, you can filter out the unwanted lines:

```
(previous awk command) | awk '$1 ~ /0$/'
```

This last `awk` command only displays the lines whose first value ends with a `0`.